# Making a library before the final executable using makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have the following makefile

```
all: yesdata

CFLAGS=-fPIC

lex.yy.c: yesdata.l yesdata.tab.h
        flex yesdata.l

yesdata.tab.c yesdata.tab.h:    yesdata.y
        bison -d yesdata.y

yesdata: lex.yy.c yesdata.tab.c yesdata.tab.h yesdata_util.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o yesdata yesdata.tab.c yesdata_util.c lex.yy.c -lyesdata -lyesprocess -ltest -ltestconf 

clean:
        rm yesdata yesdata.tab.c lex.yy.c yesdata.tab.h
```

My `lex` file is `yesdata.l`

My yacc file is `yesdata.y`

I have a C file that contains some functions `yesdata_util.c`.

The `makefile` above compiles it into a binary called `yesdata`.

Now the `main()` entry function is defined inside the `yesdata.y`. I want to move `main()` to another C file say `abcdef.c`

I want to compile `abcdef.c` and link that C file against the files
`yesdata.l`,`yesdata.y` and `yesdata_util.c`.

How do I achieve this using makefile?

Comment: strongly suggest modifying the makefile so each .c file is compiled separately and the link step is separate (and depends on the object files from the .c file compile steps.

Comment: Do you specifically want to make a shared library with the lexer and parser (in order to link them with multiple programs), or do you just want to compile them as separate object files from the one containing main and then link everything together?  Because if it's the latter, you can just do something like `yesdata: yesdata.tab.o lex.yy.o main.o` <newline,tab>`$(CC) $^ -o $@`.  The rules you already have will create yesdata.tab.o and lex.yy.o, and the default rules will be used to compile those to object files, which are then linked by the above lines.

Answer (score -1):

the '-fPIC' will generate the library file, 
so the '-o' parameter should indicate not only the name of the library, 
but also where that library is to be placed.

The compile of the abcdef.c file should be a separate step,

The link of the abcdef.o file into abcdef executable needs the '-l' parameter to let the link step know about the library.

since the library is already generated, 
the handling of the abcdef.c file does not need to know anything about the files used to generate the library.
However, the abcdef.c conversion to abcdef.o does need to depend on a .h file that contains the prototypes, etc for that library

Comment: `-fPIC` produces position independent code, a requirement for a shared library but doesn't itself produce a library (see `-shared`). For static libs you don't need it but do need to create the library archive in a separate step `ar rcs *.o`